# Does prestop hook wait for command execution in all the replicas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

we have a deployment with hpa(horizontal pod autoscaling) of maxReplicas set to 3. And in our deployment.yaml we have a preStop hook defined, which calls an API exposed in the container and a terminationGracePeriodInSeconds defined to 60 seconds(the calls are internal to the cluster and should be sufficient).
Is it guaranteed that the preStop hook waits for the execution of the request from all three pods?

````
     lifecycle:
       preStop:
         exec:
           command: [ "curl", "-XPOST", http://$SERVICE_NAME:$PORT_NUMBER/exit-gracefully ]
   terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60  ```
````

Answer (score 2):

No guaranteed as the [official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks) stated:

> The Pod's termination grace period countdown begins before the PreStop
> hook is executed, so regardless of the outcome of the handler, the
> container will **eventually terminate within the Pod's termination grace
> period**.

Comment: If there are three pods, I can see that three invocations are happening for the curl command given in preStop hook, however, it's getting load-balanced, is there a way to skip load balancing for this curl that's called from preStop hook?

Comment: Do you curl a service that front the 3 pods that are going down, or you curl another service which back by other pods (not the 3 that are going down)?

Comment: the same service that is going down.

Comment: update: I changed the url to localhost instead of SERVICE_NAME and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Yupe, that's the right way to go.